# Directory not Found-Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, pycharm

Please I need help finding My directory path.I used the `lstrip` and `rstrip` to clean off certain areas of a joined directory but still error  from  `train.txt` file the spelling and the directory path are all good and well spelt

````
...
db_root_dir='/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/DAVIS/'
fname = 'train.txt' 
//this is a line from train.txt
/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg /Annotations/480p/bear/00000.png
/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00001.jpg /Annotations/480p/bear/00001.png //and it goes down like this  in sequence but i still cannot get it to work
...


with open(os.path.join(db_root_dir, fname + '.txt')) as f:
    seqs = f.readlines()
    img_list = []
    labels = []
    for seq in seqs:
        images = np.sort(os.listdir(os.path.join(db_root_dir, 'JPEGImages/480p/', seq.rstrip('/Annotations/480p/bear/00000.png\n').strip())))
        images_path = list(map(lambda x: os.path.join('JPEGImages/480p/', seq.rstrip('/Annotations/480p/bear/00000.png\n').strip(), x), images))
        img_list.extend(images_path)
        lab = np.sort(os.listdir(os.path.join(db_root_dir, 'Annotations/480p/.png', seq.lstrip('/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg'))))
        lab_path = list(map(lambda x: os.path.join('Annotations/480p/', seq.lstrip('JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg'), x), lab))
        labels.extend(lab_path)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/dataloaders/davis_2016.py", line 129, in <module>
train=True, transform=transforms)
File "/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/dataloaders/davis_2016.py", line 46, in __init__
seq.rstrip('/Annotations/480p/bear/00000.png\n').strip())))
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/DAVIS/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg'**```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/DAVIS/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg'**
```

this error means that you are trying to open this '/Users/Myname/Desktop/Video Segementation/DAVIS/JPEGImages/480p/bear/00000.jpg' location which is not a directory. To debug this print the directory before opening

you could print the directory before opening this

```
print(seq.rstrip('/Annotations/480p/bear/00000.png\n').strip())
```

Comment: It still says no directory but i tried even checking the directory path in my terminal and it checks out

Comment: how did you fix this